# Android: Gradle: build should not fail if the file is absent

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to implement the following in gradle :

If a perticular file is not present locally and if it is also not present in central repository then biuld process should not fail.

How do I implement this with conditional dependencies? If anyone could enlighten me, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Why would you want that? If you declare a dependency you will most likely use it somwhere in your code. What should gradle do if it removes the library and can't find that lib to compile your code?

Comment: What is this "perticular file", and why would the "biuld process" fail if it is "not present locally" and "also not present in central repository". Please be **very specific** about what the file is what that the failure would be.